# How to use jQuery.stellar in React

Tags: jquery, reactjs, stellar.js

How do I have to configure my React project to be able to use the code below:

```
$(window).stellar()
```

I'm using Webpack and ProviderPlugin, and design is ready - only thing left is to install and attach Stellar library

Answer (score 0):

To use jquery with React, here is as sample code:

```
import $ from 'jquery';

... // here goes class definition and constructor 

componentDidMount() {
  $(window).stellar()
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  $(window).stellar("destroy");
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I get `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).stellar is not a function` when using as You do. jQuery is attached automaticly in provider plugin, but I think that stellar is not included by default

Comment: I was assuming you are using es6 as well as have stellar installed. What is the node module name that have stellar in it?

Comment: i'm using es6 but i haven't installed stellar, since it has never worked. Could You update Your answer to show which package do I have to install?